# PHP Dynamic Variable With this Keyword

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to generate variable variables in a class method such as:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 6; $i++) { 
    echo ${"this->year" . $i . "Season"};
}
```

I expect to get

```
$this->year1Season
$this->year2Season
```

and so on, but instead I get no output.

Note: I have already defined:

```
private $year1Season;
private $year2Season;
```

and so on at the top of the class and have defined:

```
$this->year1Season = $year1Season;
$this->year2Season = $year2Season;
```

and so on in the constructor.

The code works fine when I use the variables as:

```
echo $this->year1Season;
```

but not when I try to generate the variables dynamically.

Comment: `$this->{'year' . $i .'Season'}`

Comment: Thank you @marekful - that worked perfectly.

Comment: you can not assign $this->year1Season = $year1Season;
It would be better if you show your class code to us

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering, @marekful 's answer solved my question (the site doesn't let me select comments as answers, but I'd like to give him the props).

His answer is the following:

```
$this->{'year' . $i .'Season'}
```

Comment: Its not advised to post answer to your own question.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay That's just so that other people can more easily find the answer in case they have the same question.

Comment: Stackoverflow allow to Question and Post your own answer to help community,